# JavaScript all elements which id starts with an interpolated string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons with the same class `.btn-plus-minus` and an id that starts with "btn-plus-SomeMoreText_1_[...]".

To select all buttons, I used `var buttons = $(".btn-plus-minus[id^='btn-plus-']");`

But now I don't want all buttons, but only these that also match a number.
My `match[1]` returns "SomemoreText_1_" and I want only the buttons with ids starting with btn-plus-SomeMoreText_1_ so I tried:

```
var plusButtons = $(".btn-plus-minus[id^=`btn-plus-${match[1]}`]");
```

Unfortunately, the string interpolation inside the `id^=...` doesn't seem to work since I get the following exception:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .btn-plus-minus[id^=`btn-plus-${match[1]}`]

Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a template string in a regular string. Try making the whole string a template string:

```
var plusButtons = $(`.btn-plus-minus[id^='btn-plus-${match[1]}']`);
```